# OCSPResponse Event is not triggered with tls.connect even though requestOCSP is set

Tags: tls1.2, ocsp

By referring to the Nodejs TLS document https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#event-ocspresponse to get the OCSP status of a certification , we should expect **OCSPResponse** event when **requestOCSP** is set to *true*

I'm encountering an issue where the **OCSPResponse event** never gets triggered using the provided codes. I'm unsure what might be missing. Appreciate your assistance. Thank you

```
const tls = require('tls'),
    PORT = 443,
    HOST = 'google.com'

const options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
    servername: HOST,
    secure: true,
   // enableTrace: true,
    requestOCSP: true,
};

const client = tls.connect(PORT, HOST, options, function () {
    if (client.authorized) {
        console.log("Connection authorized by a Certificate Authority.");
    } 
    let certificate = client.getPeerCertificate(true);
    console.log("---------------")
    client.on("OCSPResponse", function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
    });
    client.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log('Received: %s',data.toString().replace(/(\n)/gm, ""));
    });
    client.end(() => {
        console.log("Client closed successfully");
    });
});
```

I tried different node version, but it did not help.

Comment: From your link with emphasis added: "... emitted if the requestOCSP option was set ... **and an OCSP response has been received**". The server may send OCSP when requested but isn't required to, and google.com doesn't. Try stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085, you are right, I am able to receive it by using `stackoverflow.com`. But I encountered another issue, since the response response is a digitally signed object, how could I parse it, thanks.